# Plot new graph with plotly FigureWidget on_click function

Tags: python, function, onclick, plotly

I am trying to make it so that upon clicking a bar on the graph, a new graph is plotted with different data. Currently, the click function works, but a new graph is not plotted:

```
# Standard plotly imports
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#dataset1
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y = [10, 20, 30, 5, 25]

#dataset2
a = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
b = [40, 80, 100, 10, 15]

#create first figure
f = go.FigureWidget([go.Bar(x = x, y = y)])
bar = f.data[0]

#click function to create new figure
def new_figure(trace, points, selector):
    for i in points.point_inds:
        print("CLICK")
        new = go.FigureWidget([go.Bar(x = a, y = b)])
        bar2 = new.data[0]
        new

bar.on_click(new_figure)

f
```

[Here's the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjMRs.png)

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong for the second figure to not plot? Thanks in advance.